# would have to + past participle

Tags: tense, past-tense

> The amendment would have to be repassed.

What time does **would have to + past participle** indicate? How is it different from **would have + past participle**?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners. For this question, start by re-examining the way the sentence is structured: modal *would* + modal *have to* + infinitive *be* + past participle *repassed*. *Would* and *have to* are each adding their own discrete layers of meaning to the verb phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that *pass*, in a legislative sense, may be either transitive or intransitive.

> `TRANSITIVE ACTIVE :` The Senate passed the bill.
>   `TRANSITIVE PASSIVE:` The bill was passed by the Senate.
>   `INTRANSITIVE      :` The bill passed.`

Now let's take your two sentences:

> The amendment would have to be repassed.

This is not a perfect construction but *will*<sup>PAST</sup> + the modal idiom *have to* = *must*,as you can see from the fact that it is followed by the infinitive *be* rather than the past participle *been*. The use of a form of *BE* followed by a past participle (*repassed*) indicates passive voice, which requires the verb to be understood as transitive. It means, approximately:

> It would be necessary to pass<sup>TRANSITIVE</sup> the bill again.

The past form of *will* may mean (1) 'future in past' reference or (2) 'modal remoteness', an unlikely or counterfactual hypothetical.

> (1) A procedural error meant that the amendment would have to be repassed.
>   (2) If we could get Sen. Blowhard to agree the amendment would have to be repassed.

---

> The amendment would have repassed.

This is a perfect construction in form, but actually represents a "double past": *would* employed in the hypothetical sense marked with a following 'perfect' to indicate past time reference.  It means, approximately:

> The bill did not pass<sup>INTRANSITIVE</sup> again in our world, but did in some alternate universe.